# How do I print a variable which is multiline string in the body of email in python

Tags: python, email-attachments, mime-message

I have this piece of code:

```
l = ["Jargon", "Hello", "This", "Is", "Great"]
result = "\n".join(l[1:])
print result
```

output:

```
Hello
This
Is
Great
```

And I am trying to print this to a body of an email as shown below, I am getting the text as an attachment rather than as-body. can anyone please tell me if I am missing something here?

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = emailfrom
msg["To"] = emailto
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fileToSend)
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
    ctype = "application/octet-stream"   
maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)
fp = open(file.csv, 'r')
attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
fp.close()
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", fileame='file.csv')
msg.attach(attachment)
msg.attach(MIMEText(result, "plain"))
server = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: Well, how does the email turn out?

Comment: It's an attachment because you're using a MIME multipart message with `msg.attach()`.  If you just want a plain text body, why are you doing it that way?

Comment: I am using MIMEMultipart() because I also have an attachment to send in the email, which i did not mention here

Comment: I am getting the text as an attachment in email, I want it in body

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], or at least all of the relevant code.

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 0):

When using `yagmail`, it works as intended.

```py
import yagmail 

yag = yagmail.SMTP(
  user=conf_yag['user'],
  password=conf_yag['password'])

l = ["Jargon", "Hello", "This", "Is", "Great"]
result = "\n".join(l[1:])

yag.send(emailto, 'test from yagmail', result)


# including attachment
yag.send(emailto, 
         subject='test from yagmail', 
         contents=result,
         attachments='somefile.txt')
```

where `conf_yag` stores your credentials, `emailto` is the receiver email address, and `'somefile.txt'` is the file attachment.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I want the attachment as well as the body of message in the same email

Comment: I added the attachment example.

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't use yagmail

Answer (score 0):

In python, `\n' means a line break.
In python email, '
' means a line break.

If you do

```
result = result.replace('\n','<br/>')
```

It should work.